# Ignore non compatible character sets

Tags: mysql

I am getting an error while trying to restore data from a dump file.

```
# mysql  < /tmp/Dump20200101.sql
ERROR 1273 (HY000) at line 1: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
```

I can edit the dump file and change the character set.

> CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `somedb_25122019` /*!40100 DEFAULT
>   CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci */ /*!80016 DEFAULT
>   ENCRYPTION='N' */;

What is the correct way to handle this error in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on [this article](https://allthings.how/how-to-fix-utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci-error-when-importing-wordpress-database/), the mysql8.0 collation `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` isn't supported in your destination database.

So replace it as you are importing it:

```
sed -e 's/COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci/g' /tmp/Dump20200101.sql | mysql
```

Comment: mysql-dump command correctly adds comment clause for character set. If mysql does not follow the hint while restoring data, then it defeats the purpose of adding extra characters in the create database statement in the first place.

Comment: note the comment - not version 4.0.1 around the entire character set and collation.assume you aren't restoring to this version, however it would of been useful to put the actual destination version into the question. You can write a bug, or patch for MySQL and they'd appreciate it more than if you didn't (https://bugs.mysql.com/).